# Why does Rust not permit type inference for local constants?

Tags: rust

I understand why type inference for module-level constants is not permitted (the same reason why type inference is not permitted for functions). However, why exactly does Rust not permit type inference for *local* constants?

```
fn main() {
    const N = 1; // error: expected `:`, found `=`
    let n = 1;   // OK
}
```

Is there a more profound reason than consistency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insofar as I'm aware, there's no distinction between a `const` inside a function and one outside.  They're both the same thing, so they follow the same rules.